# strimzi/kafka docker-compose logging configuration

Tags: kubernetes, logging, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, strimzi

Which are the environment variables to configure logging for this widely used docker image?
How can I configure zookeeper root logger level in the following ***docker-compose.yaml***?

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: strimzi/kafka:latest-kafka-2.0.1
    command: ["sh", "-c","bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties"]
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
        ## Where are this env variables specified??
        LOG_DIR: /tmp/logs
```

References:
[strimzi documentation](https://strimzi.io/documentation/)
[strimzi operators configuring logging](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/using.html#external-logging_str)

Comment: Strimzi is not designed for running in Docker Compose. It focuses on running Apache Kafka on Kubernetes using the operator pattern. So there might be no easy way to do it.

Comment: To copy the same behavior of a configmap, you'd mount a volume